# Spark won't let me create a closure

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark

So I'm attempting to create a k-fold testing function for spark, and I'm getting an interesting error that I'm not sure how to approach.

So the following code:

```
val modelErrors = tst.map(
      data => {
    val model = createLogRegressionModel(data._1, sc)
    val err = computeError(model, data._2, sc)
        err
  }
).reduce(_+_)
```

produces the error "Return statements aren't allowed in Spark closures"

but what I don't understand is that the MOST basic spark example, the word count, SEEMS to have a return statement in it's closure

```
val words = sc.parallelize(Array("spark", "isnt", "working", "right", "now"))
val counts = words.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(word => (word, 1))  <----RETURN STATEMENT IN A CLOSURE
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Is there something I'm completely missing here?!

Comment: Neither your code, or the "basic spark sample" have a return statement. Can you post a complete example?

Comment: `word => (word,1)` is an anonymous function with no external dependencies.  Note that `word` and `words` are different.

Comment: I've encounter the same problem, Spark closure cleaner complains about the non-existing return statement

Comment: Its works just fine

Comment: val words = sc.parallelize(Array("spark", "is", "working", "right", "now", "spark", "is", "awesome"))
val counts = words 
  .map(word => (word, 1))  
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.take(5).foreach(println)


(working,1)
(is,2)
(awesome,1)
(right,1)
(spark,2)